# Issue returning values with RXJS and Nestjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I'm getting some JSON from an endpoint (I'm using `@nestjs/axios` for this). The issue is that the response is an `Observable`. This complicates things when returning values. I can't seem to get async/await to work, I'm truly out of ideas...

Here's my endpoint:

```js
async getBalance({ address, network }: WalletDto): Promise<any> {
    let nativeBalance: string

    try {
      this.httpService
        .get<{ balance: string }>(
          `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/${address}/balance?chain=${network}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'X-Api-Key': 'lol',
            },
          },
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: ({ data }) => {
            nativeBalance = utils.formatEther(data.balance)
          },
          complete: () => {
            const chain = supportedChains.find(
              ({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === network,
            )

            return {
              chain,
              nativeBalance,
            }
          },
        })
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO handle error
    }
  }
```

I've messed around with `.pipe()` but don't understand what it does or how it works... Btw, `supportedChains` is a static array, not part of the fetch.

Comment: What do you want `getBalance` to return? It could either be a promise that resolves to some value (maybe it resolves to the object `{ chain, native Balance }`?), or it could be an observable which emits that same value. EDIT: You can't return the value itself, since it doesn't exist yet

Comment: Yeah I want it to return `{ chain, nativeBalance }`. Plain and simple :)

Comment: You can't return that. It doesn't exist yet. You can either wrap it in a promise, or in an observable. Do you have a preference?

Comment: well tbh I'm not too sure what an observable is lol... haven't messed around with rxjs or websockets

Comment: yeah wrapping it in a promise worked. Thanks a lot. Post an answer and I'll submit that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a super brief intro to observables: if a Promise is an object that represents exactly one eventual value, then an Observable is an object that represents a stream of *any number* of eventual values. Observables come with a collection of operator functions for manipulating the stream of values (that pipe function you mentioned is used to pass in any operators you want to apply).

If you just want to convert from observables to promises, then you can do so with the `.toPromise` property on observables. If you're using rxjs version 7 then `toPromise` is deprecated and instead you can use `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom`.

```
import { firstValueFrom } 'rxjs';
//...
async getBalance({ address, network }: WalletDto): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const observable = this.httpService.get<{ balance: string }>(
      `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/${address}/balance?chain=${network}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "X-Api-Key": "lol",
        },
      }
    );

    const { data } = await observable.toPromise();
    // OR in rxjs v7:
    // const { data } = await firstValueFrom(observable)

    const nativeBalance = utils.formatEther(data.balance);

    const chain = supportedChains.find(
      ({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === network
    );

    return {
      chain,
      nativeBalance,
    };
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

Comment: also, you could use another wrapper for Axios: [`nestjs-http-promise`](https://github.com/benhason1/nestjs-http-promise). It is promise-based.